# It is possible to create a worflow(airflow) between s3(csv file) to store it in mongodb?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

I want to create a workflow that takes the files from s3 and store the data into the mongodb, so far I came with this approach:

```
dag = DAG('s3_to_mongo',
        schedule_interval='@daily',
        catchup=False)


first_task = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', dag=dag)

s3_mongo_task = S3ToMongoOperator(s3_conn_id='', s3_bucket='', s3_key='',
                                mongo_conn_id='', mongo_collection='', mongo_method='insert',
                                mongo_db=None, mongo_replacement_filter=None, upsert=False, dag=dag)

first_task >> s3_mongo_task
```

I am using the operator for the official documentation: https://github.com/airflow-plugins/mongo_plugin/blob/master/operators/s3_to_mongo_operator.py

Answer (score 0):

Airflow and Mongo Plugin don't have support for CSV files on S3. 
You need to write your own operator.

```py
class S3CsvToMongoOperator(S3ToMongoOperator):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        s3 = S3Hook(self.s3_conn_id)
        mongo = MongoHook(conn_id=self.mongo_conn_id)

        data = (s3
                .get_key(self.s3_key,
                         bucket_name=self.s3_bucket)
                .get_contents_as_string(encoding='utf-8'))

        lines = data.split('\n')
        docs = [doc for doc in csv.DictReader(lines)]

        self.method_mapper(mongo, docs)
```